# Hiding ul li on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, navigation, hide

I'm using the bootstrap framework to develop the front end for a e-commerce site. In order to create a optimal mobile experience I want to hide the child items for the primary navigation on mobile and instead have the user click the primary items then be taken to the product page quicker where they can begin browsing items.

Is there anyway to do this?

Here is a snippet of the nav code, the entire nav is pretty long, basically I want to hide all level-2 li on mobile.

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav nav-justified horizontal-drop-down">
<li class="level-1">
<a href="#">All Products</a>
<ul>
<li class="level-2">
<a href="#">Accessories</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a media query?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     .level-2 {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

This would set the class level-2 to display none on anything under 767px wide... Obviously you can just change the width to suit your application =)

Comment: Thanks! This led me to @media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar .nav li ul a {
  display: none !important;
}
}

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped... If you load a custom style sheet in AFTER the bootstrap styles, you should be able to overwrite the bootstrap styles without the need for the important tag =)

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your CSS page:

```
.level-2 {
display: none;
```

}

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g48p4y8s/)